# How to use django-allauth username validation methods in a user update form

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth system to register users and log them in. My app should allow users to change their usernames if needed.

If I use a custom view or form to change a username, no allauth validation happens whatsoever (because default views and forms are not triggered). Thus users can easily set whatever username they wish, ignoring all restrictions specified in settings (like "preserve casing" or "minimum length restriction").

Is there any way to use default validations built in allauth outside signup/login forms?

Right now I have to manually create a custom form and use its cleaning methods for validation, which seems to be repetitive and error-prone:

```
def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    if username:
        username = username.lower()

        if len(username) < settings.ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH:
            raise ValidationError(_("Error text"))

        if username in settings.ACCOUNT_USERNAME_BLACKLIST:
            raise ValidationError(_("Error text"))

        # I need something that works like the code below and validates a username
        from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
        DefaultAccountAdapter.clean_username(username)

    return username
```

Comment: You can take the default creation form (see [docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html)), subclass it to add any required functionality and use in your view.

Comment: @SUTerliakov good idea, thank you! Although I'm still not able to use it, since SignupForm throws an error when passing an instance, which is important in updating a model. Are there any examples of such usage online?